# How can I install freefem++ on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10

I recently upgarded  to 17.10 and I don't have any idea about installation of the lastest version of freefem++. Help me please

Comment: Default is version 3.47 . FreeFem++ v 3.59 http://www.freefem.org/  → http://www.freefem.org/ff++/ftp/freefem++-3.59.tar.gz : I guess you will have to build that yourself. Patches for `3.59` are available from Fedora 28 http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/28/Everything/source/tree/Packages/f/freefem++-3.59-1.fc28.src.rpm

Answer (score 0):

You may start by installing these packages from official repository:

```
sudo apt-get install freefem-examples freefem-doc freefem++ freefem++-doc
```

Then run `stokes` example:

```
freefem /usr/share/doc/freefem-examples/stokespo.pde
```

And consult some online resources:

- https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/freefem++/freefem++.html
- https://www.cc.kyushu-u.ac.jp/scp/doc/users/lecture/2016/FreeFem++-tutorial-1.pdf
- https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/hecht/ftp/ff++/2016-Fields/FH-Lesson5-8-Fields.pdf
- https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/~suzukia/FreeFempp-tutorial-JSIAM2016/